# Change default view (home) in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

I hate Google Docs Home view. It contains a lot of documents that were shared with me and are marginally relevant to me.

I want to choose what shows when I open Docs.

In essence, I want "starred" to be my home view.

Any way to do that? Maybe a Chrome/FF extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen any extension but you can make your own userscript to redirect any time your browser hits Google Docs homepage

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Google Docs Set Homepage as Starred
// @description    Redirects the homepage to the Starred page
// @include        https://docs.google.com/
// @include        https://docs.google.com/#home
// @exclude        https://docs.google.com/#starred
// @run-at         document-start
// ==/UserScript==

location.href= "https://docs.google.com/#starred"
```

Save as whateverfilename.user.js and let your browser install it

I didn't include the tab link on from the Google bar on top.

`https://docs.google.com/?tab=oo&authuser=0#home`